# Proof that the sum of the measures of the angles of any triangle is always the same ⟺ Euclid's fifth postulate (parallel postulate)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm having trouble proving this equivalence. All I can get is that if the sum of the interior angles of any triangle is $180^\circ$, then Euclid's fifth postulate is valid.

When I try to generalize the sum of the angles of a triangle, I get stuck in the proof. I've looked in some books about this demonstration, but none provide a similar explanation beyond stating the sum as $180^\circ$, without offering a generalized approach.

Comment: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI32.html